# GET request in TeaVM

Tags: javascript, java, get, teavm

I want to make a GET request to an URL in Java so that it can be transpiled to Javascript via TeaVM. I understand that I can't use the java.net API, because it is not supported by TeaVM. So I tried to make a Javascript-function which can be used by TeaVM.

```
@JSBody(params = { "url", "callback" }, script = "fetch(url)\n"
                                                     + ".then(response => response.text())\n"
                                                     + ".then(text => callback.complete(text))\n"
                                                     + ".catch(error => callback.error(error.message));")
    static native void fetch(String url, FetchCallback callback);
```

My Java Interface is simple:

```
public interface FetchCallback {
        void complete(String result);
        void error(String message);
    }
```

When i run the install Maven target, I get this error:

*[ERROR] Method org.example.Client.fetch(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/example/Client$FetchCallback;)V is not a proper native JavaScript method declaration: its 2th parameter has wrong type*

Unfortunately my JS knowledge is very limited (hence TeaVM) so I can't make sense of this error message. Could someone please help me with how to make a GET request in TeaVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://teavm.org/docs/runtime/jso.html) `FetchCallback` must extend `JSObject` interface. BTW, TeaVM already comes with wrappers for [XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm/blob/7ff56d7a94fe723f1b9936764c0e2fd5dab54d7f/jso/apis/src/main/java/org/teavm/jso/ajax/XMLHttpRequest.java).